# Rewrite history to include a staged file

Tags: git

I'm learning git and I did this:

```
modify foo.file
git add foo.file
modify foo.file
git commit foo.file -m "yada yada"
```

Of course, because I included the file name the commit ignored the staged foo.file and commited the modified, unstaged `foo.file`.  The intention was to commit the staged `foo.file` and then add the 2nd modification.  It should have been more like:

```
modify foo.file
git add foo.file
modify foo.file
git commit -m "yada yada"
git add foo.file
git commit -m "2nd change to foo"
```

How can I rewrite history so I can commit the staged `foo.file` and make it look like it was committed before the 2nd modification?  My objective is to get diffs to appear "correct".  The changes to `foo.file` that are recorded in the staged file (that was not committed) are important and it may not be possible to recreate them accurately.  The staged `foo.file` needs to be committed (somehow) and then the 1st commit rewritten to move the skipped changes before the erroneous commit

To reproduce the state:

```
git init test
cd test
echo "1st version" > foo.file
git add foo.file
echo "2nd version" > foo.file
git commit foo.file -m "Was supposed to be 1st version"
```

The `1st version` is still present in Git and can be accessed through `cat-file` but it's not part of any commit and it's not listed in `status`.

I have gotten some progress on this by doing this:

```
git update-index --info-only --index-info
100644 <sha1-of-orphaned-modification> 0    foo.file
```

And then committing.

But when I try and reorder the commits using

```
git rebase -i --root HEAD
```

Git thinks the 2nd commit was a modification, not a new file and fails to perform the rebase.  I think I need to supply more info in the index update, but no idea what.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that you have not made a bunch of commits after the incorrect one.

First, reset your state to the previous commit.

```
git reset HEAD^
```

Next, move it into the state that you want the first commit to be, stage and commit it. Then make your second set of modifications, stage and commit again.

Comment: This does not seem to be a history rewrite, just doing the same thing over again.

Comment: @Tibrogargan, This is the minimum that you would need to do to the get the end state you desire. If you had more commits after the fact, then you would need an interactive rebase, but you'd still have to do at least these steps as part of the interactive rebase.

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clear that the change that needs to be commited is the existing staged file - not a recreation of the changes.

Comment: @Tibrogargan, Your commit command will combine the staged file with the unstaged file and commit them both. After the commit, I believe the staging area is cleared, but I'm not 100% sure of this.

Comment: @Tibrogargan, It sounds like what you are really trying to do is to recover the staged files after a commit which combined staged and unstaged changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could make the second commit and then try to do a `git rebase -i HEAD~2` and swap the ordering of the two commits around in the editor that pops up.

Comment: There's only 1 commit.  The change that should have been a commit is just a SHA-1 in the staging area

Answer (score 0):

This requires rewriting the history, so as usual, do not do it if someone has based their work on top of the commits.

First do a soft reset to the previous commit - this will keep your working area as it is, but resets the head:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

Then interactively add only the lines that you want for the first commit:

```
git add -i foo.file
git commit -m "First commit"
```

After that, you can add & commit the rest of the changes:

```
git add foo.file
git commit -m "Second commit"
```

Comment: Tried this, but got `fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~1': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`.  This is in a completely new repo with only the reproduction given above.

Comment: Try to give the sha1 of the commit then.

Comment: Ah now I see - this wouldn't work on a repo that only has one commit, since the reset command will want to reset to the commit before the one that we want to rewrite.

Comment: Using the SHA1 worked, but `add -i` is saying there are no changes.  I think maybe this is because foo.file is new - there is just the staged version (version 1) and the working version (version 2)... but nothing I've tried to do seems to change the status